# Объединение экземпляров пефаба

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Не могу найти что-то по своему вопросу, может кто-то сможет подсказать. Есть префаб, в котором есть n-ное количество экземпляров этого префаба на сцене, которые спавнятся в рандомных координатах и вращаются вокруг своей оси в разные стороны с разной скоростью. Вызываются они циклом while:

```
  Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(ncorx, 0, ncorz), Quaternion.identity);
```

В итоге на сцене появляется 20 экземпляров.
Можно ли как-то обьединить все эти экземпляры таким образом, чтобы их все вместе можно было сдвинуть на нужную величину в нужном направлении.

Comment: Метод возвращает объект инстанцирования (Returns: Object The instantiated clone.). Следовательно все их можно поместить в какую-либо коллекцию и работать с коллекцией когда надо

Comment: А в случае, если количество этих объектов часто меняется, эта коллекция должна постоянно удаляться и создаваться заново?

Comment: Да. Самое удобное это именно работать с объектами из коллекции, а не каждый раз его выискивать на игровой сцене. Поиск в коллекции значительно быстрее. Только скорее должна не коллекция удаляться, а объекты в ней.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция [Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) возвращает вам `The instantiated clone` созданного объекта, т.е. ссылку на созданный объект.
Вы можете положить это значение в переменную, а можете создать список List, в который будете динамически добавлять созданный объект:

```
List<GameObject> objects = new List<GameObject>();

GameObject newObj = Instantiate(...);
objects.Add(newObj);
```

Так как объекты со сцены могут удаляться, то можно еще, если на префаб повесить скрипт, который будет сам добавлять этот собственный объект в лист или удалять:

```
ScriptWithList script;
void Start () {
    script.objects.Add(gameObject);
}
void OnDestroy () {
    script.objects.Remove(gameObject);
}
```

А c элементами list'а можете работаете через `for`, `foreach` - как хотите:

```
for (int i = 0; i < objects.Count(); i++) {
    print(objects[i]);
}

foreach (var obj in objects) {
    print(obj;)
}
```

Comment: А если я хочу один экзмпляр после того как занесу его в список, переместить на какую-то координату отдельно, каким образом я могу это сделать?

Comment: @marquensis_13 находите его в коллекции и меняете его данные. Например  всем объектам присваивать uniqueId и по нему находить. Ещё можно вместо коллекции сделать словарь, где ключом может выступать UniqueId. Тогда будет ещё проще его найти и поработать с ним

Comment: Если вы знаете индекс этого объекта - по индексу `objects[i]`, если знаете какой-то параметр объекта - ищете его в списке циклом, вариант со словарем, предложенный @СергейМишин также верен, причем объекты можно сохранять не только по id, но и по названию, номеру и чего там вам еще хочется